# JAR built by Netbeans in Ubuntu cannot find main class in windows7

Tags: java, jar

I have a JAR built by Netbeans in Ubuntu run very well in Ubuntu. But in windows I double click the same JAR file leading to the error "could not find main class"... Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: Have included the `main-class` element within the `MANIFEST.MF`?

Comment: @MadProgrammer `main-class` or `Main-Class: `?

Comment: @MiserableVariable `Main-Class:` - little rushed :P

Comment: I asked because `java -jar` is especially finicky about spelling, whitespace and such. At least Oracle JVM is.